# Hide Panel depends on Texbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, panel

How can I make set a `Panel` objects visibility to `false` if the text in a `TextBox` is "CLOSED"?

My current code is:

```
if (Session["txtALTN1"] != "Closed")
{
    pnlALTN1.Visible = false;
}
else
{
    pnlALTN1.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: You just did it, congratulations.  What's your question?

Comment: What problems are experiencing with your code? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead?

Comment: You should chenge your condition to 'if (txtALTN1.Text != "Closed")' in case txtALTN1 is a asp textbox control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controls are not placed in the session, if txtALTN1 is your TextBox use this instead:

```
if (txtALTN1.Text != "Closed")
{
    pnlALTN1.Visible = false;
}
else
{
    pnlALTN1.Visible = true;
}
```

or simply:

```
pnlALTN1.Visible = (txtALTN1.Text == "Closed");
```